# Swift 3 nested functions vs closures

Tags: swift, nested, closures

I have a large method that does some loading and calculating so it shows an activity indicator view to inform the users they should wait. The logic is pretty complex so there are 4 places in which the data processing might break or return (everything is done on closures). Anyway, I didn't want to repeat this code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    activityView.hide()
    activityView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

in 4 places so I figured that I would write a nested function:

```
func removeActivityView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        activityView.hide()
        activityView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

but then I realised that in Swift I could also do:

```
let removeActivityView = {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        activityView.hide()
        activityView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

which is used exactly in the same way and does exactly the same from the user's point of view.

So what is the actual difference between one approach and the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same in this case. In Swift:

> Nested functions are closures that have a name and can capture values from their enclosing function.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

In fact, you could also do:

```
func foo() {
     print("Foo!")
}
let bar = foo
```

Now `foo()` and `bar()` would yield the same result. This can be done for any function that takes in no arguments.

I'm not sure how/if the compiler differentiates these two. If anyone has more information with respect to that, I would be very interested!